# Get all records that violate the polices in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have t1 which contains the users and their permissions on some dashboards, and t2 contains the logs for the users, I want to find all logs that have users who logged to dashboards not theirs.

```
T1
Id name 
1  a
1  b
1  c 
2  a
2  d
3  c
3  d
3  f 


T2 
Id name
1 a 
1 f
2 c
2 d
3 f
3 a
```

```
select * from t1 , t2 
Where t1.id = t2.id and t1.name <> t2.name
```

But it doesn't work, it gets results that are true

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: All the users who don't have permissions but have records in the log table

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   T2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   T1
  WHERE  t1.id = t2.id
  AND    t1.name = t2.name
)
```

or use `MINUS`:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM t2
MINUS
SELECT id, name FROM t1;
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1 (Id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'f' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2 (Id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'f' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'f' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL;
```

Both the queries output:

> ```
> ID | NAME
> -: | :---
>  3 | a   
>  2 | c   
>  1 | f
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b25dcaceae4c533492792164ff9032c6)*